# How can I extract the content from a div using python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im using python + selenium to scrape some data from a website and I encountered to following problem.

I have some divs of the following type:
`<div class = "element"> Data1 </div>`
`<div class = "element"> Data2 </div>`
`<div class = "element"> Data3 </div>`

I selected the element using elements = driver.get_elements_by_class_name("element")
then I looped through the elements and for each element I want to save the text in a list variable called dataArray my question is how can I select the text from the element in order to append it to the list?

```
for element in elements:
    dataArray.append(element.?)
```

Comment: try `element.text`

Answer (score 1):

you need `.text` method which is availabe in Selenium-Python bindings :

Instead of this :

```
for element in elements:
    dataArray.append(element.?)
```

use this :

```
for element in elements:
    dataArray.append(element.text)
```

you can simulate the same with `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` but I am not sure if you have the right locator for that.